# Accessing adapter inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a main **Activity.class** that runs a Fragment **(not FragmentActivity)** via `ViewPager`. And I have a custom adapter with recyclerview list inside the fragment. There is an issue with accessing adapter outside and inside the Fragment. So:

This code fully works:

```
private List<MyQuestionList> theList;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) theview.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    theList = new ArrayList<>();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

    adapter = new MyQuestionsAdapter(theList, getContext());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    updateAdapter();  // <-- ATTENTION PLEASE, I'VE CALLED THE FUNCTION INSIDE THE FRAGMENT

}

public void updateAdapter(){ // <-- METHOD IS PUBLIC
    removeItem(0);
}

***** And there is located parser's method where items are fetching from server
and adding to recyclerview via adapter successfully.
But the code is too long, and anyway there is nothing interesting :) *****

private void removeItem(int item){
    theList.remove(item);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But when I call the same method (updateAdapter) from main **Activity.class** like this (not inside the fragment on run):

```
Fragment_Questions frau = new Fragment_Questions();
frau.updateAdapter();
```

code doesn't work. Here is log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.remove(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Where adding `Fragment_Questions` Fragment?

Comment: Inside the Activity.class that calls fragment. `public void openQuestion { adding Fragment_Questions }`. openQuestion is called inside the xml-layout by `onClick="openQuestion"`

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that a `Fragment_Questions` is already added to a `ViewPager`, use the reference of the added `Fragment_Questions` object to call updateAdapter().

In the code given below, you are just creating an object but never adding it to a viewpager. Hence, the `onCreateView` method is never being called, which leads to the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: But `ViewPager` just controls tab layout and returns `Fragment_Questions` when it inits. So how to realize that scheme: User clicks on layout's element -> method `X` inside `Activity.class` inits -> method `X` calls method inside the `Fragment_Questions` ?

Comment: So how to use it from activity?